# Phonology vs phonetics : /ʁɔz/ vs [ʁoz]

Tags: phonology, phonetics, pronunciation, phonetic-symbols

It's written [on French Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_phon%C3%A9tique_international#Quantit.C3.A9_.28allongement_ou_amu.C3.AFssement.29) that the noun “rose” is represented in phonology by /ʁɔz/ whereas [Wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rose) is claiming that it should be /ʁoz/. In both case, the associated representation in common phonetics seems to be [ʁoz], which sounds correct for me as a native French speaker.

Who is right about phonology ? In case Wikipedia is, could you explain ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although /ɔ/ and /o/ do contrast in certain positions in French, the distinction is neutralized before /z/, where phonetically it's always the high-mid vowel that appears: [[oz] but never [ɔz]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_phonology#Mid_vowels). So it's a moot point which of the two to choose as your underlying representation. The French Wiki article opted for /ɔ/ presumably because this is the vowel that's usually found in closed syllables.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I can't vote up due to my lack of reputation.

Answer (score 4):

In French there is no phonological contrast between [o] and [ɔ] in closed syllables. Thus, phonologically you could analyse “rose” either as /ʁoz/ or equally well as /ʁɔz/. It is merely a matter of convention.

PS. Overlap with TKR's excellent answer.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I can't vote up due to my lack of reputation.

Comment: Actually, there is a phonemic contrast between /o/ and /ɔ/ in closed syllables for Standard French in most environments: compare *mode* /mɔd/ to *chaude* /ʃod/. (An actual minimal pair would be [*roque*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/roque) and [*rauque*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/rauque)). The contrast is absent for most speakers in *open* syllables, where they are neutralized to /o/ (in words like *mot* /mo/ and *beau* /bo/). The opposite pattern applies in Standard French to /ɛ/ and /e/, which are generally distinct in open syllables but neutralized to /ɛ/ in closed syllables.